# What does Bruce Wayne fear?

Tags: dc, batman

Bruce Wayne, or Batman, lives in the face of danger.  Fighting criminals in the shadows and facing super villains such as the Joker, Two Face or even Mr. Freeze.  What did he fear?  Did he get over his fear of bats?

Comment: Carnies. Because of their small hands...

Comment: [Snake Clowns](https://youtu.be/rznro4_W3EE?t=1m28s)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In [Knightfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightfall), Batman is dosed by the Scarecrow's fear gas in (Batman #496 KnightFall: Part 9 - "[Die Laughing](http://www.comicvine.com/batman-die-laughing/37-37457/)") in front of the Joker. It has the effect of making him hallucinate Jason Todd (Robin II) which drives him into a psychotic attack on the Joker, suggesting that Batman's fear is "loss", i.e. losing people like he lost his parents and how (at that time) he had lost Jason.

[image: Batman 496]

When he is dosed with the gas:

> ROBIN! He's killing robin! No -- not real -- Jason's already dead --
>   just visions..  from the gas..

And after:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: two of the images posted are missing

Comment: they're displaying OK for me.

Comment: I reckon it's slightly more specific: being responsible for the death of people close to him.

Comment: If only he had shown Red Hood he cared that much.  We could have avoided soooo many Red Hood issues moaning about Batman...

Answer (score 8):

Somewhat spoiler, please be careful when you are reading this if you have not seen the movie...

Something that was mentioned more than one time was the fear of death. Bruce Wayne or Batman say that they (he) does fear death.

> **Bruce Wayne:** Why didn't you just... kill me?
>  **Bane:** You don't fear death... You welcome it. Your punishment must be more severe.

And also:

> **Blind Prisoner:** You do not fear death. You think this makes you strong. It makes you weak.
>  **Bruce Wayne:** Why?
>  **Blind Prisoner:** How can you move faster than possible, fight longer than possible without the most powerful impulse of the spirit: the fear of death.
>  **Bruce Wayne:** I do fear death. I fear dying in here, while my city burns, and there's no one there to save it.

Although that does not exactly answer your question, it is an important theme of the movie.

Comment: So Batman doesn't fear death so much as he fears failure to save his city and his people?  Death by a thousand cuts.

Comment: This doesn't have to relate just to the movie.

Comment: Exactly! That's why it's a theme... that's exactly what a theme is... It uses characters and a story to show you a critique of something real.

Comment: This is almost the same answer as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24035/21267 . He fears "being responsible for people's deaths".

Answer (score 0):

Bruce wayne also fears of himself. i.e., if ever he becomes the antagonist and harms the people. His character had spoken this dialogue while having conversation with superman, in justice league.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should add some evidence, such as a quote, to back up your answer.